# Are unexpected fields ignored when deserializing an object?

Tags: java, serialization

From the docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a5172

> *Incompatible changes* to classes are those changes for which the
>   ***guarantee of interoperability cannot be maintained***. The incompatible
>   changes that may occur while evolving a class are:
>
> **Deleting fields** - If a field is deleted in a class, the stream written
>   will not contain its value. When the stream is read by an earlier
>   class, the value of the field will be set to the default value because
>   no value is available in the stream. However, this default value may
>   adversely impair the ability of the earlier version to fulfill its
>   contract.
>
> etc...

Here, with "deleting fields" as an incompatible change means:

Having e.g. a serializable class A:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -13921739827197L;

    private B fieldB;
    private C fieldC;
    // ... getters and setters for both fields
}
```

If I serialize this class now, both **fieldB** and **fieldC** will be serialized (of course B and C also implement Serializable).

Now, if I remove *fieldB* from class A:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -13921739827197L;

    private C fieldC;
    // ... getter and setter only for fieldC
}
```

If I try to serialize an instance of this class now, only fieldC will be serialized, as there's no fieldB anymore.

If now I pass this serialization to a JVM instance where the previous version of class A is used (therefore the one with *fieldB* and *fieldC*), as the seriliazed object of class *A* doesn't have *fieldB* in its serialization, the result would be an instance of the older version of class *A* with *fieldB* set to `null` (default value, just like when "Adding fields" compatible change). Of course this may lead to "null" pointer exceptions and unexpected results, this is why Oracle says that it should be considered an "incompatible change".

However, what if the opposite occurs?

For example, what if a `deserialization` of an instance of an older version of class A (both with *fieldB* and *fieldC*) occurs and the JVM has a newer version of class A (therefore, without *fieldB*)?

How will the serialization API handle this? Will it simply discard *fieldB*?

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes, what are the results, if no, why not?

Comment: Well what do you think? Whereto would the JVM serialise the data if there's no variable to serialise to...

Comment: @Smutje no, I haven't tried it yet because the question came into my mind when I was re-reading the section about `serialVersionUID` and `incompatible changes`, therefore I posted as soon as this question came into my mind :). I will try that anyway

Comment: @Neil Sorry, my comment was wrong. I meant to say - we can't be sure based on that logic alone that the deserialization won't fail with an exception.

Comment: @Duncan no problem. Easiest way is to test it :)

Comment: Yeah, I should have probably do that, I acted impulsively! Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Specification is misleading on this point.

Deletion is compatible from the point of view of Serialization itself: that is to say, it won't trigger an `IncompatibleClassChangeException.` What the Specification is trying to convey is that the *application* may experience an incompatibility.

But it shouldn't be listed under 'incompatible changes' in the Specification: from Serialization's point of view it is a change of exactly the same nature as a field insertion or reordering: a compatible change.

That is to say, and to finally and actually answer your question, the excess field in the stream will be simply discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The same specification you are reading has the answer:

> [**3.1 The ObjectInputStream Class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#a961)
>
> ...
>
> **Data for classes that occur in the stream, but do not occur in the object, is discarded.** For classes that occur in the object, but not in the stream, the class fields are set to default values by default serialization.